# Make my div wrap around another div?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

```css
div.sidebar {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #667A56;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: #47553C;
  border-width: 5px;
  clear: left;
}
img.side {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
div.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 465px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  background-color: #667A56;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-color: #47553C;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!---Sidebar--->
<div class=sidebar>

  <h2>
Header
</h2>


  <ul>

    links

  </ul>

</div>



<div class=sidebar>

  <h2>
Header
</h2>
  <img class=side>an image

</div>

<!--- Main Content --->

<div class=content>

  <h2 class=contentheader> 
header
</h2>

  <p class=content>
    contenttext
  </p>

  <p class=content>
    contenttext
  </p>
</div>

<div class=content>

  <h2 class=contentheader>
header
</h2>

  <p class=content>
    content text
  </p>

  <p class=content>
    content text
  </p>


</div>
```

So, this is my website.

[image: Basic Website Layout]

I have a header and footer and all that, but that isn't particularly important. I just want to figure out how to get the second content div to wrap around the bottom sidebar, so life is easier for me when I make later pages.

If the site's coding is needed, I can provide that too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be OK for you to do it like this: ?

Note, that it is impossible to get an Element have such are border as in the sketch, you would have to use multiply Elements doing the trick.

```css
.sidebar {
  padding: 50px 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 40%">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 59%; border: 1px solid black; height: 200px;">Main Content Bar Thing</div>

<div style="display: inline;">asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </div>
```

Comment: I tried applying the code you gave me; it didn't quite work. Based on what you said, I'm guessing my dream is impossible :(

Comment: Yes, thats the only way to do it :/ Sorry. But I'm sure you can do it somehow with multiply elements and some CSS/JS. Might just not be worth the time to get it work and be flexible enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give specific advice without the code, but you can nest divs inside each other like so:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Whatever you want inside your div goes here...<\p>
    <\div>
<\div>
```

You will need to add styling using css to get the exact layout you want

Comment: I added the code. Here's the site I'm working on. [link](http://putthetryinchemistry.xyz/)